# How to persist application state in a WinRT app using Caliburn.micro?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn micro with a WinRT application and it looks like that there's no StorageManager class, anyone has suggestions about how to persist application/ViewModels state in this case.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Caliburn.Micro but rather a general issue. You can either use Serialization but then you will have to pay attention to versioning and changes in your view model or you could save the fields you are interested in to a file using the normal IO methods or even store your view models in the database if you wish *(although i think this might be a bit extreme)*.

**Edit:** Caliburn.Micro isn't a business application framework and there have been no library that tried to integrate business functionality with CM as far as i know, so this leaves you with serialization as your best option but as i said ser/des comes with some nightmares you have to manage such as version changes, class changes, etc.

There's another project called [Catel](http://www.catelproject.com/) which is a business application framework that contains an MVVM framework, anyway Catel uses a nice object called `DataObjectBase` *( actually now it is called `ModelBase`)* which solves all problems of serialization and there is an **[article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76867/DataObjectBase)** for that on code project if you want to read it and see how they have done it.

If you wish you can use the [Catel.Core module](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Catel.Core) which is a library with a lot of features for data handling *(it contains the `ModelBase` class)* or you can take a look at the source code and see how they have solved the issue with ser/des and implement that with Caliburn.Micro in your project.

Comment: Hi Sniffer,
I know how to persist a viewmodel to a file, my question was about if someone has already integrated the ser/deserialization mechanism into an appplication based on Caliburn micro.